# Setting Content-Length Header for Magento

Tags: php, http, magento, http-headers, magento-1.5

I'm battling some site performance issues now and one of the recommendations is to disable [*chunked encoding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

Our site pages aren't large enough to need it and there's too much overhead. I'm not very familiar with HTTP headers, but what I've learned is that the "`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`" header gets set automatically if you do not have a "`Content-Length`" header.

Does anyone know how I could go about setting the "`Content-Length`" header in Magento?  It would need to work for all pages as well as for any pages that are cached (We use the Lightspeed full page caching extension).

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the *Lightspeed full page caching extension* (you need to contact their support for your issue), but as magento has a single entry point via `index.php`, you can hack it and wrap the output in a buffer:

```
ob_start();

# ... run magento here

$buffer = ob_get_clean();
```

You then set the content-length header:

```
header(sprintf("Content-Length: %s", strlen($buffer)));
```

Then sending out the buffer:

```
echo $buffer;
```

This *might* not work with your caching extension or if other extensions are breaking the output buffering chain.